# Function doesn't return true even though it works

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a small piece of code inside a function buts it's not working, even when I pull it out and try it on its own it still doesn't work. I used a MySQL Database Class https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

```
    require_once('class.mysql.php');
    $_db = new Mysqlidb('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');


    $userCredentials = array(
                        'userID' => 'asdasda',
                        'username' => 'dsdasdasd',
                        'password' => 'v423423c342c23',
                        'email' => '2423v423@gmail.com',
                        'userType' => 1,
                    );

    if($_db->insert('users', $userCredentials)) echo 'success';
```

The correct data is inserted into the database but Success is not displayed, is their a reason for this?

Comment: The class uses `affected_rows` to determine whether or not an insertion occurred. If you are using this same sample data over and over in test, perhaps it is already present and not being newly inserted?

Comment: Since you're not using some de-facto standard or well-known library, I don't think this is a valid question for Stack Overflow. There may be a bug in the library itself. If you care, you'll need to debug the library (using the same methods you'd use on your own code).

Comment: I've went quickly through the code of library - it doesn't check for errors during `execute` - this one thing tells me **do not use this library**

Comment: Do you guys recommend a database class that I could use? Or am I better coding one myself?

Comment: @GregValantine, use one of popular framework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mysqlidb::insert` is wrong. It's return [`$stmt->insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) instead of [`$stmt->execute();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). Your query does not use autoincrement value, so, you are getting 0.

Tip from comments:

> do not use this library

Answer (score 0):

You got an extra coma at the end of the array you passing as a parameter, I don't think its the problem but still...
Have you tryed to see what is really returned via var_dump?